# Where is BuildConfig.DEBUG?

Tags: android

My project doesn't seem to be aware of this new constant that's apparently auto-generated in Android Tools r17 builds:

"Added a feature that allows you to run some code only in debug mode. Builds now generate a class called BuildConfig containing a DEBUG constant that is automatically set according to your build type. You can check the (BuildConfig.DEBUG) constant in your code to run debug-only functions such as outputting debug logs."

I've confirmed that this class is not being auto-generated anywhere in my project by the new tools. I deleted all project outputs (including all gen folders) and rebuilt, and only R.java classes are being generated.

Why are the tools not generating the BuildConfig class? It may be relevant that I'm using IntelliJ.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IntelliJ doesn't generate the BuildConfig java and class files.

I assume this function is provided by the ADT plugin for Eclipse, and isn't a part of the SDK tools/common build stuff.

Comment: Makes sense. What a shame. I've logged an issue with IntelliJ. I hope they add it as this is a nice useful little feature. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-83336

Comment: Seems that guys at JetBrain have fixed this issue. I couldn't download  latest build, hopefully it will be available in a day or two :)

Comment: BuildConfig.java is now auto-generated in IntelliJ from IDE release build 11.1.2 onwards

Comment: If it's generated as part of the build process, *shouldn't* it be part of the core SDK? Not using a particular plugin or IDE shouldn't cause your build to fail! Yikes!

Answer (score 11):

I've just checked. It is generated here (in all your projects):

```
gen/package_name/BuildConfig.java
```

And contains the following:

```
/** Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY */
package package_name;

public final class BuildConfig {
    public final static boolean DEBUG = true;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help, unfortunately. That class has not been auto-generated at that location in my project. the tools have definitely updated, so it is hard to see why.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project? And of course you restart Eclipse after the installation? Sorry, I did not catch at first you're not using Eclipse. Also there is a requirement to use Ant 1.8, do you have this version?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ, not Eclipse, but yes I've cleared the build and rebuilt it, after restarting the IDE, and no difference.

Answer (score 6):

IntelliJ Idea now supports generating of BuildConfig in newest EAP

Relevant links:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-83336
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11.1+EAP

Comment: Is this a standard Android thing or an IDE thing?

Comment: Today it is IDE or build system (such as Gradle or ANT) specific thing but it's supported everywhere I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ apparently doesn't support generation of this file. I use IntelliJ to edit my code but ant to compile it, and the `BuildConfig` stuff is being generated for me. So you could either wait for IntelliJ to produce an update which generates `BuildConfig` or switch to ant for compilation.